# Xap file in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, xap

I have 2 Xap file in "MyApplication -> Bin -> Release" folder

1)MyHelloWorldSampleApp.xap(3,820KB)
2)MyHelloWorldSampleApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap(4,631KB)

Anybody can explain about whats the difference between this two.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm surprised that two XAPs are generated in the same folder. Could it be that your project is an old Windows Phone 7 app that has been upgraded to WP8? In which case, the `MyHelloWorldSampleApp.xap` is probably a remnant of the WP7 version, and can be safely deleted (just make sure to first check the file's last modification date).

Comment: @KooKiz Thanks for reply. Yes, you are right KooKiz, that was the app upgraded from wp7 to wp8.Should i delete that file, and i have one more query, if I take the xap file from debug folder, what will happen, will it work fine.

Comment: your bin file .xap is final xap for your project.if you want to upload your xap than build your project and deploye solution than deploy your xap of bin file using application deployment toll and upload it

Comment: if you want to change your xap file name than also you can do it and always use bin file xap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming convention for WP8 app is "MyHelloWorldSampleApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap". "MyHelloWorldSampleApp.xap" is most likely a remnant from the WP7 version of your project, and should be deleted to avoid confusion.

To publish on the Marketplace, it is strongly recommended to pick the release version. The debug version disables some optimizations to work better with the debugger. Since it's not possible to attach the debugger to an application published on the Marketplace, there's strictly no point in publishing the debug version.